# Passing ChartContext in Rust

Tags: rust, plot, traits

I'm trying to refactor out some repetitive plotting code in rust, but I'm running into a problem passing around the chart context.

The function that I've written is below.

```rust
pub fn plot<DB: DrawingBackend, CT: CoordTranslate>(
    &self,
    chart: &mut ChartContext<DB, CT>,
    title: String,
    style: RGBColor,
    ) {
    chart
        .draw_series(LineSeries::new(
            self.xys().collect::<Vec<(f64, f64)>>(),
            &style,
        ))
        .unwrap()
        .label("Old Model")
        .legend(|(x, y)| PathElement::new(vec![(x, y), (x + 20, y)], &style));
    }
```

The above is a direct copy and paste from working plotting code, but I can't seem to pass the chart object into this function.  The specific error is

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'b> &'b DynElement<'static, DB, (f64, f64)>: PointCollection<'b, <CT as CoordTranslate>::From>` is not satisfied
   --> src/data.rs:50:7
    |
50  |         .draw_series(LineSeries::new(
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `for<'b> PointCollection<'b, <CT as CoordTranslate>::From>` is not implemented for `&'b DynElement<'static, DB, (f64, f64)>`
    |
note: required by a bound in `ChartContext::<'a, DB, CT>::draw_series`
   --> /home/adam/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/plotters-0.3.5/src/chart/context.rs:126:24
    |
120 |     pub fn draw_series<B, E, R, S>(
    |            ----------- required by a bound in this associated function
...
126 |         for<'b> &'b E: PointCollection<'b, CT::From, B>,
```

I'm not entirely sure where the `From` trait is being called in my brief code, so I'm not sure where to start on fixing this.  What would be the proper way to pass this chart around?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on [GitHub](https://github.com/plotters-rs/plotters/issues/314#issuecomment-1209402317), `From` is a type parameter on `CoordTranslate` that must match the type of the coordinates (e.g. `(f64, f64)` if the chart uses double precision for the x and y coordinates).

The functioning example would be:

```rust
pub fn plot<DB: DrawingBackend, CT: CoordTranslate<From = (f64, f64)>>(
    &self,
    chart: &mut ChartContext<DB, CT>,
    title: String,
    style: RGBColor,
    ) {
    chart
        .draw_series(LineSeries::new(
           self.xys().collect::<Vec<(f64, f64)>>(),
           style,
        ))
        .unwrap()
        .label(title)
        .legend(move |(x, y)| PathElement::new(vec![(x, y), (x + 20, y)], style.clone()));
    }
```